# DRY way of making a simple list API endpoint using generic views in django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to autocomplete usernames over ajax on my site so I want an API endpoint that returns just a simple array with strings such as:

```
[
  "john",
  "doe",
  "cool_rick123",
  ...
]
```

...with optional filtering.

Now, I can think of a couple of clumsy ways to do this, but what would be the best practice DRY approach using generic views in django rest framework? I could use a ListAPIView but that would serialize it into objects in a list, not just strings of names in a list as fas as I know.

Comment: Do you know that you _need_ the flattened version of the users with only the names?  I would just serve up the user instances as whole objects and optimize when you actually find it to be a UI performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a User model with attribute as username which you want to autocomplete

## serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ('username')
```

## viewsets.py

```
class UserAutocompleteApi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_query = self.request.query_param.get('username')
        queryset = User.objects.filter(username__icontains='')
        return queryset
```

Your url pattern may look like /users/autocomplete/?username=(username)

Here username is optional. If you dont pass username as a get argument, It will still return list of all usernames